# Reshape 4D Numpy Image data

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array, reshape

I had **4** RGB images in an array of shape `(4,32,32,3)`. Then I divided these images in **16** equal *8x8* blocks (64 represents the *8x8* block), `decoded_imgs.shape = (4,16,64,3)` , **3** represents the colour channels. After some processing now I want to *reshape them again* as `(4,32,32,3)` by placing each block to its original location. I have tried by using reshape function but it destroys the image data.

```
data_new = decoded_imgs.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,32,32,3)
```

Comment: How do you create `decoded_imgs`?

Comment: "decoded_imgs = (4,16,64,3)...I created them by converting 4 RGB images to 16 equal 8x8 blocks. 64 represents the block size i.e 8x8=64,  3 is the channel dimension.

Comment: @Alexender Exactly _how_ did you "convert 4 RGB images to 16 equal 8x8 blocks"? It would be helpful to know.

Comment: I used reshape and swapaxes. 

    rarray.reshape(32//8, 8, -1, 8)
                 .swapaxes(1, 2)
                 .reshape(-1, 8, 8))